# How to handle multiple comparisons in a three-arm clinical trial?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, survey, clinical-trials

I have 3 arms in a trial. I want to compare results of a survey before during and on completion of a treatment. Data is not normally distributed. What test should I use?

Comment: Are subjects randomised into the three arms? Is it a valid assumption that here is no difference between the groups at baseline? Is it a valid assumption that the during-treatment value is between the pre-treatment and post-treatment values (a monotonic relationship)? Are the pre/during/post values available for each subject? What is your null hypothesis? What kind(s) of difference(s) are you interested in, what should the test be sensitive for?

Comment: Does the survey lead to one or to multiple outcome variables? If there are multiple do they have to be combined or evaluated independently?

Comment: I've updated your title with what I seem to understand from your rather vague question (see the points raised by @GaBorgulya). Feel free to update if I missed something.

Comment: What type of data do you have? is it categorical/classification data?  such as "patient did/didn't respond"?  or do you have continuous data? such as "patient has blood pressure of xx"? or a mixture or the two?  also I have never heard of the term "three-arm" before.  What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Kruskal–Wallis test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) to perform a test for 
$$
H_0: m_1 = m_2 = m_3 \> , 
$$
where $m_i$ is the median of the $i$th group.

If the $p$-value is $< 0.05$, you could conduct a post hoc test using Bonferroni correction. 
Take a look at [this website](http://yatani.jp/HCIstats/KruskalWallis). It might be helpful.

Comment: The K-W test (like the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test) does not test medians.  It tests concordance probabilities or Hodges-Lehmann locations (like pseudomedians).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann-Whitney_U.  These tests are special cases of the proportional odds ordinal logistic model, which allows for various generalizations, including multiway layouts and covariate adjustment.